# Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P \in L(V)$ by $P(u+w) = u$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V = U \oplus W$, where U and W are nonzero subspace of V. Define $P\in L(V)$ by $P(u+w)= u$ for $u \in U$ and $w \in W$. Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of P.

Assuming all the notation is clear so far... by using definition of eigenvalues:

$Pv = \lambda u$

Then, $\lambda u = \lambda u + \lambda w$.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Note that $P|_U$ (restriction of $P$ to $U$) is an identity map, while $P|_W$ is the zero map. (You might want to assume that you have basis vectors for $U$ and $W$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tunococ gives a hint towards the straightforward approach to this problem. I'll give an alternative approach:

Note that since $Pv \in U$, we have $P^2v = Pv$ for any $v$. Therefore $$P^2 = P.$$ Now if $u$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Pu = \lambda u$, so $$P^2u = P\lambda u = \lambda Pu = \lambda^2 u.$$ But since $P^2 = P$, $\lambda^2u = \lambda u$, and since $u \ne 0$, this can only be if $$\lambda^2 = \lambda.$$ Therefore $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$. Since $W = \ker P$, it is the eigenspace for $0$, and since $Pu = u$ if and only if $u \in U$, $U$ is eigenspace for $1$.

This is an example of a more general theorem: if $Q$ is some polynomial with scalar coefficients and $Q(M) = 0$ for a linear operator $M$, then the eigenvalues $\mu$ of $M$ also satisfy $Q(\mu) = 0$. On rare occasions, this result can be useful in finding eigenvalues (though the particular example here is by far the most commonly encountered use).